# Как оптимизировать несколько запросов mySQL

Tags: php, оптимизация, mysql

При выводе списка групп на сайте в цикле к каждой группе даётся небольшая статистика: кол-во участников в группе, кол-во тем и т.д.

При каждом прохождении цикла выполняются несколько запросов SELECT (COUNT).

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT id, title FROM group");
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);

do {
   $query = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_group = ".$row["id"]);
   $sum = mysql_fetch_array ($query);

   $query2 = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id_group = ".$row["id"]);
   $sum2 = mysql_fetch_array ($query2);

   $query3 = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE id_group = ".$row["id"]);    
   $sum3 = mysql_fetch_array ($query3);
   echo "Группа: ".$row["title"];
   echo "Колличество чего-то: ".sum;
   echo "Кол-во2: ".sum2;
   echo "Кол-во3: ".sum3;
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result));
```

Как-то не красиво всё это, да и сервак наверное грузить будет. И это из-за каких-то циферок. Можно ли эти запросы или оптимизировать или в один собрать как-то? Подсчёт ведётся в разных таблицах. Спасибо.

Comment: и в чем проблема? сделайте один запрос по всем группам, присоедините к ним статистику через left join. Выполнять запросы в цикле - признак плохого тона программирования, в любом приложении.

Comment: Это как? Ещё и с join'ами...

Comment: @alexlz, см ответ @ksladkov. Правда там скобок многовато и вьюхи создавать необязательно, но смысл в томбы сразу выбирать для всех групп необходимую инфу и потом уже бежать по запросу, не делая новых запросов.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE id_group = $id) as count1, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id_group = $id) as count2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE id_group = $id) as count3

так же можно через UNION

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE id_group = $id UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id_group = $id UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 WHERE id_group = $id

Comment: Вот, вот. Это оно, а интересно какой из них лучше всё же (по скорости например или ещё по какому нибудь параметру)?

Comment: выполните обе запроса в консоли MySQL и сравните время выполнения.

Comment: Последний вопрос. Возможно ли вставить один из этих запросов в запрос:
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT id, title FROM group");
ещё перед циклом?

Comment: эти варианты ничем не лучше исходного. от запросов в цикле избавиться не удастся.

Comment: через подзапросы получится - если` колонка будет одна (у вас их 2, id,title)
если возвращаемый результат данного запроса будет только одна линия.
я бы не стал смешивать эти запросы.

Answer (score 2):

Удобно создать вспомогательные вью, как-то так:

```
CREATE VIEW groups1 AS SELECT COUNT(*) as count, id_group FROM table1 GROUP BY id_group;
CREATE VIEW groups2 AS SELECT COUNT(*) as count, id_group FROM table2 GROUP BY id_group;
CREATE VIEW groups3 AS SELECT COUNT(*) as count, id_group FROM table3 GROUP BY id_group;
```

И собирать уже из них:

```
SELECT id, title, groups1.count, groups2.count, groups3.count FROM (((group LEFT OUTER JOIN groups1 ON group.id=groups1.id_group) LEFT OUTER JOIN groups2 ON group.id=groups2.id_group) LEFT OUTER JOIN groups3 ON group.id=groups3.id_group)
```